# Create block between header and main

Tags: magento-2.1, custom-block, header.panel

I am facing issue with creating a block between `header.container` and `main`. so that I can put the banner over there. And I need the banner in home page only

please help me for the same.

Comment: actually where you want to Display banner section after Menu or Before Menu ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried and its working for me.

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="page.wrapper.second" as="page_wrapper_second" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="my-custom-div" before="main.content">
               <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="your_banner_block">
                     <arguments>
                          <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">your_banner_block</argument>
                     </arguments>
               </block>
        </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

You have to place your banner block instead of "**your_banner_block**" block.

Comment: Thanks its working ..but i want the banner for home page only..but it is coming in all pages..help me to get in home page only as a banner

Comment: i need the block with whole 100% width at the middle of the page...above product.info.details in individual product details page

Answer (score 1):

You can use Widget

- On the Admin Panel

  > Content > Elements > Widgets
- In the upper-right corner of **Widgets** workplace, click on Add New Widget button.
- In the **Settings** section:

  - Choose **CMS Static Block** type in the Type box.
  - Choose the current theme you are applying in the Design Theme.
  - Click Continue button.

[image]

**Complete the Layout Updates**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**I have found the answer** ...that we should create the **custom xml** file for that ..and assign the custom xml to the home page from admin side..mention in the custom xml whatever we want and positions..then it will come