# Adding a Block between Menu and Breadcrumbs

Tags: layout, blocks, xml, magento-2.2.5

Going a bit nuts trying to get my head around this. Debug mode doesn't help me.

I'm trying to add a block just before the `</header>` on only Product Pages. I've created a phtml file with my content (banner). And I've added the below code to:

`<theme>/<child>/Magento_Catalog/templates/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<referenceContainer name="root">
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="banner" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/banner.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
<move element="banner" destination="header" after="-"/>
```

In my head, the above:

- Loads Block in the root of the page with `<referenceContainer name="root">`
- Then moves the Block to the `header` container: `<move element="banner" destination="header"...`
- And puts it at the very bottom: `...after="-"/>`

Clearly though, it does not. I've used a ton of trial-and-error with varying results. It either loads in places I don't want or doesn't appear at all.

**Edit**

It appears that `</header>` is part of `header.phtml` and so I cannot accomplish what I set out to to do.

However, I'd also be happy with the block loading BETWEEN `</Header>` and `<div class="breadcrumbs">`. This seems more achievable having looked closer at the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I was implementing core answers incorrectly or whether the solution was purely specific to the Porto Theme. However, having realised that I couldn't add a block between the `Navigational Menu` and `</header>` (because they were hardcoded into one file) - I instead aimed to load the block directly after `</header>`.

I then implemented this (without the `<move...` line) which seems to work as expected.

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
    <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="banner" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/banner.phtml" after="porto_header"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

I know what Widgets could serve as a potential solution, but having looked into this, the Widget block loads quite a few `divs` further down the page. Therefore wasn't close enough. If this wouldn't bother you, then I recommend checking out [this article](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225117/create-block-between-header-and-main) on stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

To be 100% sure, you want to add new block at the the end of 
`</header>`?
If yes, maybe should just add this new block at the end of **header.container** container?

```
<referenceContainer name="header.container">
    <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="banner" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/banner.phtml" before="-"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: I've just tried your solution using both `before` and `after`. Unfortunately, the block doesn't load at all.

Comment: hmm, maybe you should add another container? I mean check how it is done in the core `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` there you have referene to the `header.container` and before adding a block they add some containers - `header.panel.wrapper` and `header-wrapper` which contain blocks with templates

Comment: Just looking into this further now. Brain drained after such a long day, so probably gonna pick this back up in the morning. Note: I edited question based on recent findings.